# grep multiple file types recursively

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to figure out how to search for "_iterator_tag" string in all sub directories recursively and in files with extensions .cpp, .h, .hpp, .cxx, .inl
for now all I can do is search each of these file types separately as below
grep -R "_iterator_tag" --include '*.cpp'
Is there a quicker way to search all of these file types together?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/).  It's great for searching source code (and not looking in images, or RCS artifacts, like .svn directories)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify multiple instances of `--include` on the command line (they are "or"ed together).

Edit: Specifically

```
 grep -r --include '*.cpp' --include '*.h' --include '*.hpp' --include '*.cxx' --include '*.inl' "_iterator_tag" /some/path
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
find /some/path -name \( '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' -o -name '*.hpp' -o -name '*.cxx' -o -name '*.ini' \) | xargs grep "_iterator_tag"
```

Answer (score 0):

I define the following aliases in my .bashrc

```
ffg() { eval find $1 | xargs -n 1 grep -nH $2 2>/dev/null ; }
fc() { ffg "-name \*.c -o -name \*.cpp" "$*"; }
fh() { ffg "-name \*.h -o -name \*.hpp" $* ; }
fch() { ffg "-name \*.c -o -name \*.cpp -o -name \*.h -o -name \*.hpp" $* ; }
```

So I'd typically do:

```
cd <root subdir>    
fch _iterator_tag
```

Of course you'd need a different set of file types.